# Using a cron job in cPanel to automate e-mail notifications: only sending one e-mail at a time?

Tags: php, email, cron

I have set a “cron job” to run once per hour on the hour. No matter how many posts go up, they are queued. When the next hour ticks, only ONE post is e-mailed out from the queue to each subscriber. For example, if there are five new job postings queued up at 2:30PM and 3:00PM strikes, our subscribers will only be notified of the first job posting. Then, at 4:00 our subscribers will receive the next post in the queue and so forth until all five e-mails go out. When there is nothing left in the queue, no more e-mails will go out. If I switch the cron job to run once per day, it would run similarly except once per day, so if I get five job posts in one day, the fifth job posting won’t be seen by our e-mail subscribers until the fifth day after it was posted.

At first, I thought this was an error, but I finally concluded that it is supposed to work this way. I was expecting all five job posts to go out at 3:00PM to all subscribers.

Is this typical of how a cron job usually runs? I was hoping I could have all e-mail notifications sent out at once instead of one at a time. Maybe there is a batch command I can use?

below is the command I am using in cPanel.

```
bin/wget -O /dev/null "url here"
```

Comment: This might be because your hosting provider might not allow you to "mass-mail" people using their servers, try checking with them to make sure that they allow this before you try to figure out what, or if anything is wrong.

Comment: This is really more of a question of your business requirements.  While on the surface it may seem odd (or even problematic depending on expected queue size vs. script execution rate), I can't say whether this approach is "right" or "wrong", as it all depends solely on what the business requirements are.  This also really has nothing to do with cron (which just determines execution interval), but rather what is the logic in the script being executed. If the logic in the script is to configured to execute the entire queue, then it will execute the entire queue.